# Is it possible to find a web url based on this script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a registration page as an assignment at school at the teachers web page. But all he gave us was the `_register.js` that he uses on that site and wanted us to see if we could find the web page with the actual sign up form.

Is this even possible? It's not `/index/register` or `/index/user/register`, I've also tried to use Tamper in chrome to see if I could find the registration page during the loading of the scripts.. also I can't find it in the indexation using google `"site:x.com"`

The script looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tos').colorbox({
    href: "/index/tos",
    'width': '80%',
    'height': '80%',
    'closeButton': true
  });
  try {
    $(document).bind('registerSuccess', bindings.onRegisterSuccess);
    $(document).bind('registerSuccessFromPromote', bindings.onRegisterSuccessFromPromote);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  $('.sign-up-form .form-response').css('height', '0px')
  $('.sign-up-form .registerBtn').click(function() {
    removeAlert();
    $(this).find('.loadingImage').show();
    var that = $(this);
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
      return false;
    }
    $(this).addClass('disabled');
    var data = {
      'fullName': $('.sign-up-form input[name="fullName"]').val(),
      'email': $('.sign-up-form input[name="email"]').val(),
      'password': $('.sign-up-form input[name="password"]').val(),
      'checkTerms': $('.sign-up-form input[name="checkTerms"]:checked').val(),
      'referrer': $('.sign-up-form input[name="referrer"]').val(),
      'clr_lrn_token_id': $('.sign-up-form input[name="clr_lrn_token_id"]').val(),
      'clr_lrn_token_val': $('.sign-up-form input[name="clr_lrn_token_val"]').val()
    }

    function success(result) {
        console.log(result.code + result.response);
        if (result.code == 200) {
          displaySuccess("Success. Redirecting...");
          if (!result.fromPromote) {
            $(document).trigger('registerSuccess');
          } else {
            $(document).trigger('registerSuccessFromPromote');
          }
        } else if (result.code == 500) {
          displayAlert(result.response);
        }
        $(that).find('.loadingImage').hide();
        $(that).removeClass('disabled');
      }
      //$('.sign-up-form .form-response').removeClass('ajax-success').html('Loading...').height('auto').show();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: serverUrl + '/api/register-process',
      success: success,
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json'
    });

    console.log($('.sign-up-form').val());
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried it yourself to see if it is possible or not?

Comment: Have tried for two days..

Comment: You want to find out the reference page??

Comment: I was asked to find the site where this script is showing in its sign-up-form not the script itself

Comment: Tried downloading the html files on the site to your pc using some website downloader and then do a search for _register.js?

Comment: Yes there is no _register.js downloaded when I have downloaded the html files from the site, either it's hidden or something.

Comment: also when I try the API -> /api/register-process I get {"code":500,"response":"Please enter a your Name.<BR>Please enter your email.<BR>Please enter a valid password.<BR>Please check Terms of Use."}

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but could you maybe try to console.log(serverUrl).
Code there makes a POST request to AJAX, with what looks like site url which is made into a variable serverUrl.
In this particular snippet of code, i can't seem to find where "serverUrl" was declared, nor was i able to console.log it out myself.

Comment: Should be a comment, as it does not answer the question

Comment: Would love to, but i don't have enough reputation to comment on a question. My apologies.

Comment: This was a good suggestion, but I can't read the elements in the script. I get serverUrl is not defined( when I'm located inside the script.